# Prevent duplicate objects being added to List<object> while retaining the ability to have two object of the same name?

Tags: c#, list, object, duplicates

I have attempted this over and over, but I'm now just going in circles.

I have a set of mostly unique job files stored externally, from these files I'm collection information and storing it in my program via a List.

On occasion, I have two job files named the same (this unfortunately cant be avoided) but containing different data (the most unique of which is a DateTime string).

My program works by polling 3 locations for these files (all locations are mirrored so the same data is present in each), collecting the information then outputting the info to a ListView window dependent on current status of each job file.

The issue I'm having is preventing duplicate entries being added to my List resulting in 69 objects in the list for only 23 jobs files.

To avoid having duplicates output in the listview, I attempted to use a dictionary to store known keys based on the job file name, however this falls over when reaching the second file that is named the same as an existing entry. Resulting in me only seeing 21 jobs in a list that should contain 23 (I also get an exception thrown). I got around this by appending something to the end of the second entry, but this isn't ideal, and was found to cause other complications later on.

Any ideas?

Here's what I have so far.

```
public List<object> PendingJobsArray = new List<object>();
public List<object> ActiveJobsArray = new List<object>();
public List<object> CompletedJobsArray = new List<object>();

public JobObject PendingJobs = new JobObject();
public JobObject ActiveJobs = new JobObject();
public JobObject CompletedJobs = new JobObject();

    private void updatePending(int index, XmlParser xmlParser)
    {
        if (Program.PendingJobsArray.Count == 0)
        {
            Program.KnownPendingJobs.Add(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Name"), xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "DateTime"));
            JobObject PendingJobs = new JobObject();
            PendingJobs.jobObjectName = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Name");
            PendingJobs.jobObjectState = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "State");
            PendingJobs.jobObjectDiscName = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "DiscName");
            PendingJobs.jobObjectPercentComplete = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "TotalPercentComplete"));
            PendingJobs.jobObjectDateTime = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "DateTime");
            PendingJobs.jobObjectRequested = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Requested"));
            PendingJobs.jobObjectCompleted = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Completed"));
            PendingJobs.jobObjectFailed = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Failed"));
            PendingJobs.jobObjectPriority = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Priority"));
            // PendingJobs.jobObjectServer = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue("Server");
            // PendingJobs.jobObjectOperation = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue("Operation");
            Program.PendingJobsArray.Add(PendingJobs);
        }
        else if (Program.KnownPendingJobs.ContainsKey(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Name")))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Program.PendingJobsArray.Count; ++i)
            {
                if (xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "State") == "Write")
                {
                    Program.PendingJobsArray.RemoveAt(index);
                }
                else
                {
                    PendingJobs.jobObjectName = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Name");
                    PendingJobs.jobObjectState = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "State");
                    PendingJobs.jobObjectDiscName = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "DiscName");
                    PendingJobs.jobObjectPercentComplete = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "TotalPercentComplete"));
                    PendingJobs.jobObjectDateTime = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "DateTime");
                    PendingJobs.jobObjectRequested = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Requested"));
                    PendingJobs.jobObjectCompleted = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Completed"));
                    PendingJobs.jobObjectFailed = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Failed"));
                    PendingJobs.jobObjectPriority = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Priority"));
                    Program.PendingJobsArray[index] = PendingJobs;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (Program.KnownPendingJobs.ContainsKey(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Name")))
        }
        else
        {
            Program.KnownPendingJobs.Add(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Name"), xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "DateTime"));
            JobObject PendingJobs = new JobObject();
            PendingJobs.jobObjectName = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Name");
            PendingJobs.jobObjectState = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "State");
            PendingJobs.jobObjectDiscName = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "DiscName");
            PendingJobs.jobObjectPercentComplete = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "TotalPercentComplete"));
            PendingJobs.jobObjectDateTime = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "DateTime");
            PendingJobs.jobObjectRequested = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Requested"));
            PendingJobs.jobObjectCompleted = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Completed"));
            PendingJobs.jobObjectFailed = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Failed"));
            PendingJobs.jobObjectQuantity = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Quantity");
            PendingJobs.jobObjectPriority = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Priority"));
            //PendingJobs.jobObjectServer = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue("Server");
            //PendingJobs.jobObjectOperation = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue("Operation");
            Program.PendingJobsArray.Add(PendingJobs);
        }
    }
```

**Updated** code based on comments below,

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.Specialized;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace SOERequestProgress
    {
        class XmlSplitter
        {
            // Declarations
            private static string[] COMPLETED_STATES = new string[2]
        {
          "ERROR",
          "COMPLETE"
        };

            private static string[] PENDING_STATES = new string[1]
        {
          "PENDING"
        };

            private static string[] ACTIVE_STATES = new string[1]
        {
          "PAUSED"
        };

            private const string STATE_ERROR = "ERROR";
            private const string STATE_COMPLETE = "COMPLETE";
            private const string STATE_PENDING = "PENDING";
            private const string STATE_ACTIVE = "PAUSED";

            public static JobObject PendingJobs = new JobObject();
            public static JobObject CompletedJobs = new JobObject();
            public static JobObject ActiveJobs = new JobObject();

            //public static JobObject x;

            public static int intI = 0;

            // Add additional info from parsed XML (Currently only "Name" and "State" are collected.
            public static void splitXml(string JobList, out List<JobObject> Active, out List<JobObject> Completed, out List<JobObject> Pending)
            {
                bool flag = false;
                int num1 = 0;
                string text = "";
                string xmlString = "";
                while (!flag)
                {
                    if (num1 < 3)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            xmlString = JobList;
                            flag = true;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            ++num1;
                            text = text + "Try (" + num1.ToString() + ") " + ex.Message + "\n";
                            Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        break;
                }
                if (!flag)
                {
                    int num2 = (int)MessageBox.Show(text, "Job list error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
                }
                else
                {
                    XmlParser xmlParser = new XmlParser();
                    if (!xmlParser.setXmlString(xmlString))
                    {
                        int num3 = (int)MessageBox.Show("Error parsing job list server response.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
                        flag = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int num3 = xmlParser.setElementName("Job");
                        for (int index = 0; index < num3; ++index)
                        {
                            string elementAttrValue1 = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Name");
                            string elementAttrValue2 = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "State");
                            if (isState(elementAttrValue2, PENDING_STATES))
                            {
                                updatePending(index, xmlParser);
                            }
                            else if (isState(elementAttrValue2, COMPLETED_STATES))
                            {
                                updateCompleted(index, xmlParser);
                            }
                            else //if (isState(elementAttrValue2, ACTIVE_STATES))
                            {
                                updateActive(index, xmlParser);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Active = Program.ActiveJobsArray;
                Completed = Program.CompletedJobsArray;
                Pending = Program.PendingJobsArray;
            }

            private static void updatePending(int index, XmlParser xmlParser)
            {
                var jobName = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Name");
                var pendingJob = Program.PendingJobsArray.Find(x => x.jobObjectName == jobName);

                if (pendingJob == null)
                {
                    JobObject newPendingJob = CreateJob("Pending", index, xmlParser);
                    Program.PendingJobsArray.Add(newPendingJob);
                }
            }

            private static void updateCompleted(int index, XmlParser xmlParser)
            {
                var jobName = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Name");
                var CompletedJob = Program.CompletedJobsArray.Find(x => x.jobObjectName == jobName);

                if (CompletedJob == null)
                {
                    JobObject newCompletedJob = CreateJob("Completed", index, xmlParser);
                    Program.CompletedJobsArray.Add(newCompletedJob);
                }
            }

            private static void updateActive(int index, XmlParser xmlParser)
            {
                var jobName = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Name");
                var activeJob = Program.ActiveJobsArray.Find(x => x.jobObjectName == jobName);

                if (activeJob == null)
                {
                    JobObject newActiveJob = CreateJob("Active", index, xmlParser);
                    Program.ActiveJobsArray.Add(newActiveJob);
                }
            }

            private static JobObject CreateJob(string jobType, int index, XmlParser xmlParser)
            {
                if (jobType == "Pending")
                {
                    JobObject x = new JobObject();
                    x.jobObjectName = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Name");
                    x.jobObjectState = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "State");
                    x.jobObjectDiscName = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "DiscName");
                    x.jobObjectPercentComplete = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "TotalPercentComplete"));
                    x.jobObjectDateTime = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "DateTime");
                    x.jobObjectRequested = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Requested"));
                    x.jobObjectCompleted = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Completed"));
                    x.jobObjectFailed = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Failed"));
                    x.jobObjectQuantity = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Quantity");
                    x.jobObjectPriority = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Priority"));
                    //x.jobObjectServer = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue("Server");
                    //x.jobObjectOperation = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue("Operation");
                    return x;
                }
                if (jobType == "Completed")
                {
                    JobObject x = new JobObject();
                    x.jobObjectName = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Name");
                    x.jobObjectState = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "State");
                    x.jobObjectDiscName = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "DiscName");
                    x.jobObjectPercentComplete = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "TotalPercentComplete"));
                    x.jobObjectDateTime = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "DateTime");
                    x.jobObjectRequested = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Requested"));
                    x.jobObjectCompleted = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Completed"));
                    x.jobObjectFailed = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Failed"));
                    //x.jobObjectServer = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue("Server");
                    //x.jobObjectOperation = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue("Operation");
                    return x;
                }

                if (jobType == "Active")
                {
                    JobObject x = new JobObject();
                    x.jobObjectName = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Name");
                    x.jobObjectState = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "State");
                    x.jobObjectDiscName = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "DiscName");
                    x.jobObjectPercentComplete = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "TotalPercentComplete"));
                    x.jobObjectDateTime = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "DateTime");
                    x.jobObjectRequested = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Requested"));
                    x.jobObjectCompleted = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Completed"));
                    x.jobObjectFailed = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Failed"));
                    x.jobObjectPriority = Convert.ToInt32(xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Priority"));
                    //x.jobObjectServer = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue("Server");
                    //x.jobObjectOperation = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue("Operation");
                    return x;
                }
                return null;
            }

            private static bool isState(string jobState, string[] knownStates)
            {
                bool flag = false;
                for (int index = 0; index < knownStates.Length; ++index)
                {
                    if (jobState.ToUpper().Equals(knownStates[index]))
                    {
                        flag = true;
                        //break;
                    }
                }
                return flag;
            }
        }
    }
```

This new code doesn't appear to be correct and I cant see where its failing, but its filling my CompletedJobArray with over 200 entries in a matter of seconds.

My ListView is only showing 1 entry (its filtered for unique jobs) and on checking the contents of the Array, its adding the same jobObject for all 200+ entries.

Can anyone spot the flaw in this code?

**Update 2:** IEqualityComparer implemented, further errors encountered.

The below code are the implementation of Equals and GetHashCode.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SOERequestProgress
{
    class JobComparer : IEqualityComparer<JobObject>
    {
        public JobComparer(Func<JobObject, object> keySelector)
        {
            KeySelector = keySelector;
        }

        public bool Equals(JobObject x, JobObject y)
        {
            return KeySelector(x).Equals(KeySelector(y));
                //x.jobObjectName == y.jobObjectName &&
                //x.jobObjectDateTime == y.jobObjectDateTime;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(JobObject job)
        {
             return KeySelector(job).GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation throws the errors below,

```
Error   1   'SOERequestProgress.JobObject' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<SOERequestProgress.JobComparer>.GetHashCode(SOERequestProgress.JobComparer)'   C:\Users\youngs\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SOERequestProgress\SOERequestProgress\SOERequestProgress\JobObject.cs 9   11  SOERequestProgress

Error   2   'SOERequestProgress.JobObject' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<SOERequestProgress.JobComparer>.Equals(SOERequestProgress.JobComparer, SOERequestProgress.JobComparer)'    C:\Users\youngs\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SOERequestProgress\SOERequestProgress\SOERequestProgress\JobObject.cs 9   11  SOERequestProgress
```

**Update 3:** Ok I'm nearly about to admit defeat, as I don't seem to be able to get my head round how the IEqualityComparer works... and I'm back to banging me head on the keyboard >.<

The code below now gets 72 jobs in the CompletedJobsArray, which equates to 24 jobs duplicated 3 times!!!

```
private static void updateCompleted(int index, XmlParser xmlParser)
        {
            var jobName = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "Name");
            var jobDate = xmlParser.getElementAttrValue(index, "DateTime");
            // Commented line below has same affect as uncommented line, except it always returns true....
            //var CompletedJobs = Program.CompletedJobsArray.Distinct(new JobComparer(x => new { x.jobObjectName, x.jobObjectDateTime }));
            var CompletedJobs = Program.CompletedJobsArray.Find(x=>x.Equals(jobDate));

            if (CompletedJobs == null)
            {
                JobObject newCompletedJob = CreateJob("Completed", index, xmlParser);
                Program.CompletedJobsArray.Add(newCompletedJob);
            }
            else
            {
                // Code below causes issues with IEnumerable
                //UpdateJob("Completed", index, CompletedJobs, xmlParser);
            }
        }
```

I have 24 jobs, but when the poll of the 3 locations for these job files happens, I only need the 24 unique jobs added to the array.... What am I doing wrong?

**Update 4** Duplication still occurs... but not in the List...

Ok, so a little further on, and I am finding that my List conatins the correct number of jobs, with no duplication occuring.

However, when a new job enters the List, output from the program (in the UI) gets duplicated for some jobs but not all.

I cant seem to pin down a reason for this, as I've tried to keep things as simple as possible, and am using one list (which is confirmed as working as intended) and am generating my output to a listview from there.

Heres offending section of code,

```
private void SortViews()
{
    var Jobs = Program.JobsArray;
    Program.JobsArray.Sort((a, b) => String.Compare(a.jobObjectDateTime, b.jobObjectDateTime));
    if (Jobs.Count >= 0)
    {
        foreach (JobObject Job in Jobs.Where(x => PENDING_STATES.Contains(x.jobObjectState)))
        {
            if (Job.inPendingView && Job.inPendingView)
            {
                Job.inCompletedView = false;
                CompletedJobsView.Items.Remove(PendingJobsView.FindItemWithText(Job.jobObjectName));
                Job.inActiveView = false;
                ActiveJobsView.Items.Remove(ActiveJobsView.FindItemWithText(Job.jobObjectName));
                ListViewItem item = PendingJobsView.FindItemWithText(Job.jobObjectDateTime);
                item.SubItems[0].Text = Job.jobObjectName;
                item.SubItems[1].Text = Convert.ToString(Job.jobObjectPriority);
                item.SubItems[2].Text = Job.jobObjectDiscName;
                item.SubItems[3].Text = Convert.ToString(Job.jobObjectRequested);
                item.SubItems[4].Text = Job.jobObjectDateTime;
            }
            else
            {
                string[] brr = new string[6];
                ListViewItem item;
                brr[0] = Job.jobObjectName;
                brr[1] = Convert.ToString(Job.jobObjectPriority);
                brr[2] = Job.jobObjectDiscName;
                brr[3] = Convert.ToString(Job.jobObjectRequested);
                brr[4] = Job.jobObjectDateTime;
                item = new ListViewItem(brr);
                item.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                PendingJobsView.Items.Add(item);
                Job.inPendingView = true;
                Job.inActiveView = false;
                Job.inCompletedView = false;
                Job.isActive = false;
                Job.isCompleted = false;
                Job.isPending = true;
            }
        }

        foreach (JobObject Job in Jobs.Where(x => ACTIVE_STATES.Contains(x.jobObjectState)))
        {
            if (Job.isActive && Job.inActiveView)
            {
                Job.inPendingView = false;
                PendingJobsView.Items.Remove(PendingJobsView.FindItemWithText(Job.jobObjectName));
                Job.inCompletedView = false;
                CompletedJobsView.Items.Remove(CompletedJobsView.FindItemWithText(Job.jobObjectDateTime));
                //ActiveJobsView.Refresh();
                ListViewItem item = ActiveJobsView.FindItemWithText(Job.jobObjectName);
                item.SubItems[0].Text = Job.jobObjectName;
                item.SubItems[1].Text = Convert.ToString(Job.jobObjectPriority);
                item.SubItems[2].Text = Job.jobObjectDiscName;
                item.SubItems[3].Text = Convert.ToString(Job.jobObjectCompleted) + " of " + Convert.ToString(Job.jobObjectRequested);
                item.SubItems[4].Text = Convert.ToString(Job.jobObjectFailed);
                item.SubItems[5].Text = Convert.ToString(Job.percentComplete) + "%";
                item.SubItems[6].Text = Convert.ToString(Job.jobObjectState);
            }
            else
            {
                Job.isActive = true;
                string[] crr = new string[7];
                ListViewItem item;
                crr[0] = Job.jobObjectName;
                crr[1] = Convert.ToString(Job.jobObjectPriority); 
                crr[2] = Job.jobObjectDiscName;
                crr[3] = Convert.ToString(Job.jobObjectCompleted) + " of " + Convert.ToString(Job.jobObjectRequested);
                crr[4] = Convert.ToString(Job.jobObjectFailed);
                crr[5] = Convert.ToString(Job.percentComplete) + "%";
                crr[6] = Convert.ToString(Job.jobObjectState);
                item = new ListViewItem(crr);
                item.ForeColor = Color.DarkOrange;
                ActiveJobsView.Items.Add(item);
                Job.inActiveView = true;
                Job.inPendingView = false;
                Job.inCompletedView = false;
                Job.isActive = true;
                Job.isCompleted = false;
                Job.isPending = false;
            }
        }

        foreach (JobObject Job in Jobs.Where(x => COMPLETED_STATES.Contains(x.jobObjectState)))
        {
            if (Job.isCompleted && Job.inCompletedView)
            {
                Job.inPendingView = false;
                PendingJobsView.Items.Remove(PendingJobsView.FindItemWithText(Job.jobObjectName));
                Job.inActiveView = false;
                ActiveJobsView.Items.Remove(ActiveJobsView.FindItemWithText(Job.jobObjectName));
                //CompletedJobsView.Refresh();
                ListViewItem item = CompletedJobsView.FindItemWithText(Job.jobObjectName);
                item.SubItems[0].Text = Job.jobObjectName;
                item.SubItems[1].Text = Job.jobObjectDiscName;
                item.SubItems[2].Text = Convert.ToString(Job.jobObjectCompleted) + " of " + Convert.ToString(Job.jobObjectRequested);
                item.SubItems[3].Text = Convert.ToString(Job.jobObjectFailed);
                item.SubItems[4].Text = Convert.ToString(Job.jobObjectState);
                item.SubItems[5].Text = Job.jobObjectDateTime;
            }
            else
            {
                string[] arr = new string[6];
                ListViewItem item;
                arr[0] = Job.jobObjectName;
                arr[1] = Job.jobObjectDiscName;
                arr[2] = Convert.ToString(Job.jobObjectCompleted) + " of " + Convert.ToString(Job.jobObjectRequested);
                arr[3] = Convert.ToString(Job.jobObjectFailed);
                arr[4] = Convert.ToString(Job.jobObjectState);
                arr[5] = Job.jobObjectDateTime;
                item = new ListViewItem(arr);
                if (Job.jobObjectState == "ERROR")
                {
                    item.ForeColor = Color.Firebrick;
                }
                if (Job.jobObjectState == "COMPLETE")
                {
                    item.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                }
                CompletedJobsView.Items.Add(item);
                Job.inCompletedView = true;
                Job.inPendingView = false;
                Job.inActiveView = false;
                Job.isCompleted = true;
                Job.isActive = false;
                Job.isPending = false;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Any ideas whats causing this behavior?

Thanks again :)

Comment: Have you tried implementing your own Equals for JobObject?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use List<object>? You can use the strongly typed List<JobObject> which can make the filtering easier.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to C#. could you give an example of what you mean please?

Comment: Is it a typo or you forgot to declare private Func<JobObject, object> KeySelector; ? Apart from this, the code looks fine. I am able to compile the code after adding the private declaration.

Comment: Yep I missed it (knew I was missing something, just couldn't put my finger on it). The code now throws cannot convert from IENumerable.JobObject to JobObject errors for "CompletedJob", "PendingJob" and "ActiveJob". Seems more searching is required lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of complicating the code, it would be easy to work with a single list here.

```
List<JobObject> jobs = new List<JobObject>();

// Code that adds / updates a job
var newJob = CreateJob(state);
// The equality comparer should check for a job name and job date of two jobs to ensure the uniqueness
var existingJob = jobs.Find(x => x.Equals(x, newJob));

if(existingJob != null)
{
  // Update your existing job
  // If you want to calulate the time interval between job start till end, you can have more properties
  // indicating the jobPendingStartTime, jobActiveStartTime etc.
}
else
{
  jobs.Add(newJob);  
}

// Code to find jobs
var pendingJobs = jobs.Where(x => PENDING_STATES.contains(x.jobObjectState));
var activeJobs = jobs.Where(x => ACTIVE_STATES.contains(x.jobObjectState));
var completedJobs = jobs.Where(x => COMPLETED_STATES.contains(x.jobObjectState));

// Bind to different list views
```

IEqualityComparer Implementation:

```
public class JobObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Date { get; set; }
    //Other properties
}

public class JobObjectComparer : IEqualityComparer<JobObject>
{        
    public bool Equals(JobObject x, JobObject y)
    {
        return x.Name == y.Name &&
               x.Date == y.Date;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(JobObject job)
    {
        return job.GetHashCode();
    }

    // Then use it as follows.
    // JobObject newJob = CreateJob();
    // var comparer = new JobObjectComparer();
    // var existingJob = jobsArray.Find(x => comparer.Equals(x, newJob));        
    // if(existingJob != null)
    // { 
    //   Job Exists
    // }
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Ok so I now have this working, see my updated code above. However only 21 of 24 jobs are being added to the JobArray, leaving 3 (that are duplicate names, but don't contain the same data) missing from view. How do I get these jobs included using this method?

Comment: In that case, as Stilgar mentioned, you have to implement an IEqualityComparer for the class JobObject, create a new JobObject always and modify the code to find the job as Program.PendingJobsArray.Find(x=>x.Equals(newJob)).How to implement and IEqualityComparer can be found in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762203/Csharp-LINQ-and-IEqualityComparer

Comment: Right, I've added an IEqualityComparer, however I'm now getting 2 compile errors that searching doesn't seem to bring up any info on. The errors are as follows                                                                                                'SOERequestProgress.JobObject' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<SOERequestProgress.JobComparer>.GetHashCode(SOERequestProgress.JobComparer)' the same error is found for Equals.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Can you post the IEqualityComparer implementation if possible?

Comment: Added an Update two with code to my original question. Thanks again :)

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry to do this, but I've added a 3rd update... Seems somethings still not right, as 24 unique jobs are now added to my array, but are duplicated 3 times due to a poll of 3 locations for the same data...

Comment: I have provided an implementation of IEqualityComparer in the updated answer. It is better to implement in on the JobObject class for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and have found that the custom implementations of Equals is not being used in either case... (or so it seems anyway). by running code with a break point on just before existingJob is checked, I have found that existingJob always returns null. I don't know  enough about IEqualityComparer's to be able to dig into this atm... Any suggestions on what may be causing this to happen?

Comment: My bad. Not sure what I was thinking, I will edit the answer with proper code, calling Equals with a single argument will invoke Object's Equals method.

Comment: Right so I now know how to use an IEqualityComparer to override my JobObjects Equals method. This is working great to get the Completed jobs to display as intended. However, my issue still remains unsolved to some extent, as by using this method, any "Active" or "Pending" jobs which receive status updates, are being added multiple times to my strongly typed list. One solution I can think of for this situation is to clear the List before each pass, and then repopulate it with all known jobs of each type. This causes display issues though, so any other suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: A small question. Let us say you have 3 lists. PendingJobs, ActiveJobs and CompletedJobs. A Job can be there only in any one of the list at any point of time right? A pending job which is moved to active state should not be there in PendingJobs collection. Am I right in understanding the context here?

Comment: That's correct, The JobName will always be the same (and may occasionally be duplicated), but each JobName contains a different date, and current state field. The latter two update frequently during job processing, but most other fields remain static. So for example JobA enters the system @ 9:00am on 17/02/15, it starts in a "Pending" state, then at 9:01am it enters an "Active" state. The JobObject at this point, would need to move from "Pending" to "Active" and would need to reflect the new "Time" of 9:01am as the JobObject collected would have been updated and a new timestamp will be added.

Comment: Just to note, I'm open to all suggestions on this and would be willing to rewrite most if not all of my existing code to get this done the way I'm hoping to implement it. Also if it helps, I'm outputting the "Jobs" in each List to a corresponding ListView, so I'll need to be able to bind or reflect one to the other (once Ones working as intended I'm sure Id be able to  do this, but for the minute populating this list correctly is the priority :))

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Out of curiosity, how would you track the existing Job? The DateTime variable for an active or Pending Job changes each time the jobs status is updated (which includes the job being paused, or pre-processing). So if I were to pause a job while in an active state, the DateTime would change and currently I would end up with a new ActiveJob of the same name being added. The easiest way to resolve this would be to ensure no jobs are of the same name, however that unfortunately is beyond my control.

Comment: There should be at least an identifier or a set of properties which uniquely identify the job. If the DateTime gets changed every time and it is used for checking equality, I think it would not be possible to track the job. You might need to rethink the design or add an ID to each of your jobs.

Comment: The only thing I can think is that the index in each array for the job would normally be the same. IE JobA would be at index 0, JobB at 1, then another JobA at index 2. If I can ensure that no updated jobs are added this may work, in that I would need to edit the IEQualityComparer to check x.Index == y.Index && x.JobName == y.JobName. I'll edit my code and see where this leads, will post back with results :D

Comment: Another update (please see my original post), I'm still getting duplication, but not in an expected way, and cant seem to find a cause for it. Effectively though when a new job enters the list, I get some but not all of the entries in the listview duplicated, but upon checking the List that this is generated from, the correct amount of jobs is found with no duplication occuring.

Answer (score 2):

Define a custom [IEqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) for your PendingJobs object. Then you can easily tweak the comparison as you see fit and compare all the fields or a subset of fields. Then you can create a HashSet and feed it this comparer. You can also use a dictionary if it is better as it also accepts IEqualityComparer.

Comment: Tried to up vote this as it was helpful (even though it wasn't marked as answering my question), I don't have enough rep yet though, so I'll just say thanks here :) thanks!